# PySpark: How do I specify dropna axis in PySpark transformation?

Tags: python, data-cleaning, pyspark

I would like to drop columns that contain all null values using `dropna()`. With Pandas you can do this with setting the keyword argument `axis = 'columns'` in `dropna()`. [Here](https://gist.github.com/aculich/fb2769414850d20911eb) an example in a GitHub post.

How do I do this in PySpark ? `dropna()` is available as a transformation in PySpark, however `axis` is not an [available keyword](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html).

Note: I do not want to transpose my dataframe for this to work.

How would I drop the furniture column from this dataframe ?

```
data_2 = { 'furniture': [np.NaN ,np.NaN ,np.NaN], 'myid': ['1-12', '0-11', '2-12'], 'clothing': ["pants", "shoes", "socks"]} 

df_1 = pd.DataFrame(data_2)
ddf_1 = spark.createDataFrame(df_1)
ddf_1.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I  know this is a bit late, but I struggled with this also. This is my attempt at removing null columns from a Spark Dataframe.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import when, isnull

colsthatarenull = df.select([(when(isnull(c), c)).alias(c) for c in df.columns]).first().asDict()
namesofnullcols = {key:val for key, val in colsthatarenull.items() if val != None}.values()
df = df.drop(*namesofnullcols)
```

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to use the column name like:

```
df_1 = df_1.drop('furniture')
```

Comment: Yes that works. Problem is I have a large data-frame and do not want to find each column manually. So hard coding is not really an option.